# How should I use sudo from an upstart script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, node.js, upstart, su

I am using upstart to run my node.js app on an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance.  I have had a few issues getting it to work, summarized below.

In my script I had a line like this:

```
exec sudo -u www /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/foo/app.js >> /var/log/foo.sys.log 2>&1
```

When run, the job never got passed `stop/waiting`, and when I turned on `log-priority debug` I saw this line:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

I ended up at [this post](http://maymay.net/blog/2010/03/17/how-to-work-around-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo-without-sacrificing-security/) talking about `visudo` and why I shouldn't use it and how it recommends using `--session-command` instead.  So I changed the line to:

```
exec su --session-command="/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/foo/app.js >> /var/log/foo.sys.log 2>&1" www
```

The log now says `(sys) Starting` but `initctl status foo` still says `foo stop/waiting`.

It this point I am not sure how what to do to get this working, any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I have been over [this post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312171/can-i-run-node-js-with-low-privileges) and the results are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: "How should I use `sudo` from an upstart (or any other kind of system startup/init) script?"
A: "You shouldn't".

Sudo is really designed to be used interactively (hence the `you must have a tty to run sudo` message) -- It's not the right tool to be used in non-interactive startup scripts.

---

To do what you want requires a little hackery because Upstart doesn't support launching jobs as unprivileged users (yet -- hopefully one day they'll fix this problem). The question was [asked and answered over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/213416/running-upstart-jobs-as-unprivileged-users), but I'll reproduce it here as it's equally valuable for sysadmins:

> Asking on the #upstart channel on freenode, the official take on the
>   matter is:
>
> A future release of Upstart will have native support for that, but for
>   now, you can use something like:

`exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' username -- /path/to/command [parameters]`

Comment: (There are also a number of other options mentioned on that SuperUser answer which might be worth investigating.  If you find this answer useful please go visit the original question/answer on SuperUser & upvote those as well)

Comment: How amazingly painful this has been, but thank you.  I went back and voted up the q&a from su too.

Comment: I don't see why the ugly su exec is better than a single sudo. Also, with both commands, any output redirection does not seem to be written by the unprivileged user but by root.